# How to query with XPathSelectElement

Tags: c#, xpath, linq-to-xml

I have the following type of XML that contains a large number of DocType values:

```
<InvalidDocTypes>
  <DocType>DocType1</DocType>
  <DocType>DocType2</DocType>
</InvalidDocTypes>
```

I am trying to query the XML for the specific doc type using the following:

```
document.PriorDocumentType = "DocType1"
var node = doc.XPathSelectElement("//InvalidDocTypes[DocType='" + document.PriorDocumentType + "']");
```

I am only expecting node to be null when there is no value in the XML, but I am always getting just a null.  Would it be better to use a Linq query against the XML, or what am I doing wrong with the XPathSelectElement.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does your actual XML has *default namespace*? (look for `xmlns="whatever"`)

Comment: No, it doesn't have a namespace. Switching from XElement.Load to XDocument.Load as Damian has below worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and it seems to be working - please verify the console application below. It prints the whole *InvalidDocTypes* element when *DocType* exists and null when it does not exist:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var xml = @"<InvalidDocTypes>
  <DocType>DocType1</DocType>
  <DocType>DocType2</DocType>
</InvalidDocTypes>";

            var documentType = "DocType1";

            var xmlDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            var node = xmlDocument.XPathSelectElement("//InvalidDocTypes[DocType='" + documentType + "']");
            Console.WriteLine(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I was using XElement.Load(xmlfile) and that wasnt working for me. Once I changed to XDocument.Load(xmlfile) like you have it worked.